# The highest value from list-distinct

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me with query, I have table

```
vendorid, agreementid, sales

12001      1004         700
5291       1004         20576
7596       1004         1908
45         103           345
41         103           9087
```

what is the goal ? 
when agreemtneid >1 then show me data when sales is the highest

```
vendorid  agreementid   sales
5291      1004          20576
41        103           9087
```

Any ideas ?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY agreementid ORDER BY SIGN (SIGN (agreementid - 2) + 1) * sales DESC)
```

### Explanation

1. We break table MyTable into partitions by `agreementid`.
2. For each partition we construct a ranking or its rows.
3. If `agreementid` is greater than 1 ranking will be equal to `ORDER BY sales DESC`.
   Otherwise ranking for every single row in partition will be the same: `ORDER BY 0 DESC`.

See how it looks like:

```
SELECT *
    , SIGN (SIGN (agreementid - 2) + 1) * sales AS x
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY agreementid ORDER BY SIGN (SIGN (agreementid - 2) + 1) * sales DESC) AS rnk
FROM MyTable

+----------+-------------+-------+-------+-----+
| vendorid | agreementid | sales | x     | rnk |
+----------|-------------|-------+-------+-----+
|  0       | 0           | 3     | 0     | 1   |
| -1       | 0           | 7     | 0     | 1   |
|  0       | 1           | 3     | 0     | 1   |
| -1       | 1           | 7     | 0     | 1   |
|  41      | 103         | 9087  | 9087  | 1   |
|  45      | 103         | 345   | 345   | 2   |
|  5291    | 1004        | 20576 | 20576 | 1   |
|  7596    | 1004        | 1908  | 1908  | 2   |
|  12001   | 1004        | 700   | 700   | 3   |
+----------+-------------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Then using `TOP 1 WITH TIES` construction we leave only rows where `rnk` equals 1.

Answer (score 4):

Well you could try using a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AgreementID ORDER BY Sales DESC) RowID
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE AgreementID > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM Vals
WHERE RowID = 1
```

This will avoid you returning multiple records with the same sale.

If that was OK you could try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable mt INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT AgreementID, MAX(Sales) MaxSales 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE AgreementID > 1
) MaxVals ON mt.AgreementID = MaxVals.AgreementID AND mt.Sales = MaxVals.MaxSales
```

Comment: Another way to have the 2nd result (all ties) is by modifying the 1st. Either change `ROW_NUMBER()` to `DENSE_RANK()` or  use `MAX(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY AgreementID) MaxSales` and then `WHERE Sales = MaxSales` in the external Where.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 sales FROM MyTable WHERE agreemtneid > 1 ORDER BY sales DESC
```

Comment: Maybe you meant TOP 1 WITH TIES?

Comment: The user only needs the Max value of sales when the condition satisfied, it may or maynot be a duplicate value.

Comment: Your query returns only one row whereas user needs one row for each agreementid that is greater than 1 and all rows for agreementid that is less than or equal to 1.

Comment: You are on the wrong track since this query returns only one row.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i misinterpreted your question. my answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know the business logic behind agreement_id > 1.  It looks to me you want the max sales (with ties) by agreement id regardless of vendor_id.

First, lets create a simple sample database.

```
-- Sample table
create table #sales
(
  vendor_id int,
  agreement_id int,
  sales_amt money
);

-- Sample data
insert into #sales values
(12001, 1004, 700),
(5291, 1004, 20576),
(7596, 1004, 1908),
(45, 103, 345),
(41, 103, 9087);
```

Second, let's solve this problem using a common table expression to get a result set that has each row paired with the max sales by agreement id.

The select statement just applies the business logic to filter the data to get your answer.

```
-- CTE = max sales for each agreement id
;
with cte_sales as
(
  select
    vendor_id,
    agreement_id,
    sales_amt,
    max(sales_amt) OVER(PARTITION BY agreement_id) AS max_sales
  from
    #sales
)

-- Filter by your business logic
select * from cte_sales where sales_amt = max_sales and agreement_id > 1;
```

The screen shot below shows the exact result you wanted.

[image]